# Installing Text (Texture) Livecoding Library

Tags: haskell, build, installation, build-process, livecoding

Rephrased:

There's a livecoding environment called Text (or Texture) written in Haskell (author: Alex Mclean/yaxu). It's not available on hackage, and it requires hand-installation, both of itself and of some dependencies. (A list of the dependencies can be found here: http://yaxu.org/text-update-and-source/).

What's the proper way to build/install it? Specifically, how does a person install and (importantly) configure each component, and in what order?

Comment: Thanks for your interest!
It seems some people have closed the question because they don't understand it, ah well.
Sorry texture (as it is now known) is really difficult to install, in fact I don't know if anyone else has done it.  However right now I'm working on a live cd containing it for a workshop this weekend, and plan to make debian packages too.  I'll make a mailing list for it soon so I can work with anyone interested in making this more widely installable too.

Comment: @yaxu I have nominated for reopening

Comment: @yaxu that sounds great. The live CD will be for Debian? Looking forward to the mailing list also.

Comment: Would anyone else like to nominate this for reopening? I think it's a valid question. (Alternatively: how have I written this wrong?).   I was going to put a bounty up for this, because I really would like to know, and it's a "fringe" question, but I can't now.